# Bash/Shell Script - arithmetic operator failing

Tags: bash, shell, math

I'm trying to slow down my infinite loop if CPU load exceeds certain limit, but, its just not working out right, below is the code. The if condition always results true

```
c=1
while [ $c -le 1 ]
do
#echo "Welcome $c times"
#php BALHABLH.php

IN=$(cat /proc/loadavg);

set -- "$IN"
IFS=" "; declare -a Array=($*)
echo "${Array[@]}"
echo "${Array[0]}"
echo "${Array[1]}"

#var = ${Array[1]}



x=$(expr "${Array[1]}" )

if [ $x > 0.91 ]
then
    echo "CPU LOAD > 0.91"
    sleep 2
fi


(( c++ ))
done
```

Comment: Thought about using `nice` and delegate load handling to your scheduler?

Comment: `>` is a redirection operator. You want `-gt`.

Comment: @n.m. Unless this is ksh93, floating point arithmetics would not work..

Comment: I got Centos 64 bit 6.something. I wonder if we can multiply with 100, then convert to integer? I'm really poor in bash, noob in php, therefore seek help here. THanks to ya all for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `bc` for floating point comparison and use `(( ... ))` for arithmetic expressions:

```
if (( $(bc -l <<< "$x > 0.91") == 1 ))
```

Also don't use `cat`, use:

```
IN=$(</proc/loadavg)
```

Comment: dogbane, tried your tip, now I'm getting this error: line 21: ((: == 1 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "== 1 ")

Answer (score 0):

Bash only handles integers. To handle floats pipe to `bc` like this:

```
[ $(echo " $x > 0.91" | bc -l) -eq 1 ]
```

`bc` returns `1` if the comparison is true. We compare with 1 (using the -eq operator).

Validation

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash  
x="$1"
if [ $(echo " $x > 0.91" | bc -l) -eq 1 ]; then
   echo greater;
else 
   echo smaller;
fi
$ ./test.sh 0.5
smaller
$ ./test.sh 1.5
greater
```

You can also simplify your script a bit like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
c=10
for (( i=1;i<=c;i++ )); do
    load=$(awk '{print $2}' /proc/loadavg)
    echo "$i: load is $load"
    if (( $(echo "$load > 0.91" | bc) == 1 )); then
        echo "CPU LOAD > 0.91"       
        sleep 2
    fi
done
```

Comment: Dear user000001, After implementing your advise, now I'm getting this error: "integer expression expected"

Comment: After this fix: "[ $(echo " $x > 0.91" | bc -l) -eq 1 ]" I'm now getting this error: ./loop1.sh: line 21: bc: command not found
./loop1.sh: line 21:  0.51 > 0.91: command not found
./loop1.sh: line 21: [: -eq: unary operator expected

Comment: do you have `bc` on your system? try `echo " 1+1" | bc` from a console

Comment: you right mate, the problem is here:  echo " 1+1" | bc
-bash: bc: command not found
Should I fire yum install bc now"

Comment: @user17183 Yes install bc and you will be fine. I also simplified your script a bit.

Comment: Kudos to user000001 & you all!

Answer (score 0):

Bash cannot use floating point arithmetic. You could do something like this:

```
if [ $( echo "$x > 0.91" | bc ) -eq 1 ]; then
```

Comment: Thank you so much people. with your help, the code is working now!